# Use custom CSS variables with SASS functions

Tags: css, function, variables, sass, colors

```
:root {
  --red: #f00;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: darken( var( --red ),15% );
}
```

Outputs the error:

> Error: $color: var(--red) is not a color.

Ofcourse this works perfectly fine with regular SASS variables. The code below works as expected:

```
$red: #f00;

div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: darken( $red,15% );
}
```

Built in CSS variables are a personal preference due to their ability to be accessed with javaScript.

### Is it possible to use CSS Variables with SASS functions? Any known solutions or workarounds would help. Even Hacks.

Link to Codepen in SCSS environment: https://codepen.io/user-devsandbox/pen/vYmMzwb

Comment: Take a look [here](https://medium.com/beyn-technology/using-css-variables-in-scss-functions-9521be4de4e3)

Comment: *Is it possible to use CSS Variables with SASS functions?* --> no, it's not. Check the duplicate for worarkounds